# How to count all the numbers that is generated?

Tags: javascript

What i'm trying to do:

- Count all the numbers that is generated every 5 seconds.

Actual Results

- Generates only numbers but, doesn't count them.

Expected Results

- Counts all the numbers that is generated and shown next to the question.

```js
function generator() {
  number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
  setTimeout(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number;
      generator();
    }, 5000);
  })
}

function add() {
var count = 0
  var element = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  if (element.innerHTML) {
  count++
  document.getElementById("demo1").textContent = count++;
  }
}

generator();
add();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
How many numbers was generated?
<p id="demo1"></p>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("demo1").textContent`, shouldn't this be equal to `count` instead of `count++`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use `setInterval` for repeated calls, and the `data` attribute to store the current count.

Extract the calls of `document.getElementById` to avoid look-for elements per `setInterval` cycle.

```js
var demoElem = document.getElementById("demo");
var countElem = document.getElementById("demo1");

function generator() { 
  var interId = setInterval(function() {    
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    demoElem.textContent = number;    
    add();
  }, 2000);
}

function add() {
  countElem.dataset.count = Number(countElem.dataset.count) + 1;
  countElem.textContent = countElem.dataset.count;    
}

generator();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
How many numbers was generated?
<p id="demo1" data-count='0'></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `add()` only once. You probably want to call it from inside the `generate()` function. Additionally `var count = 0` should be outside of the `add()` function so that its value gets persisted across calls.

Sidenotes:

- You increase `count` two times per `add()` call.
- The outer `setTimeout` inside `generate()` is useless.
- `number` is a leaking global, you should declare it with `var`